# Как реализовать асинхронный ввод в консоль

Tags: c++, многопоточность, потоки-данных, callback

При чтении (*fgets*) из стандартного потока ввода, все остальные операции останавливаются в ожидании ввода.

Как реализовать асинхронный ввод?

Может можно как-то на `callback`'и повесить?

Comment: А чего должно делать ваше приложение без данных из fgets ?

Comment: Может быть, через многопоточность?

Comment: IronVbif, принимать данные через recvfrom.


mikillskegg, может быть... Можно, пожалуйста, поподробнее? Линк на статью, примерчик приветствуется...

Comment: Посмотрите на [poll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)/[select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) Imho в вашем случае poll удобней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если есть такая проблема, может быть делать `fgets` в том месте, когда эти входные данные уже непосредственно требуются вместо того, чтобы делать его в начале, а потом ждать когда пройдут всяческие запросы-вычисления и наконец дойдёт время до применения данных, полученных в `fgets`.
2. Как уже подсказали, вынести `fgets` в отдельный поток. Там, где Вы делаете `fgets` сейчас, создать отдельный поток, в котором будет запрос `fgets` и синхронизовать основной и "запрашивающий" потоки через событие, например.

Comment: Мне что-то вроде чата нужно. Поэтому ожидание ввода должно висеть постоянно.

Спасибо, буду пробовать делить на потоки.